# Husserl's Cartesian Mediations

Tags: reference-request, husserl

What should I read to get a clear outlook of Husserl's Cartesian Meditations? I tried reading "Routledge Philosophy Guidebook to Husserl and the Cartesian Meditations" but it's not going too well. I also tried "Husserl: A Guide for the Perplexed" but that went even worse. Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get out of Cartesian Meditations, is there some project you are pursuing? Are you familiar with Husserl's other works? There are [online notes](http://www.arasite.org/cartmeds.html), [lectures](http://sweb.uky.edu/~rsand1/phi516/Lectures/02_Husserl_CM.pdf) and [blog posts](http://voiceimitator.blogspot.com/2009/07/edmund-husserl-cartesian-meditations.html) on Cartesian Meditations, even [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tov_UIBXthQ).

Comment: For starters have you read and understood Descartes? Do you know much about Kant's theoretical philosophy?

Answer (score 4):

I have in general had difficulties with the series your first book belongs to, if that's any consolation. You could try : Dermot Moran, 'Edmund Husserl: Founder of Phenomenology', London : Polity, 2005 (ISBN 10: 0745621228 / ISBN 13: 9780745621227). This has a chapter on the CM. Other chapters also throw light contextually.

There's also Joel Smith, 'Experiencing Phenomenology: An Introduction', London : Taylor Francis, 2016 (ISBN 10: 0415718937 / ISBN 13: 9780415718936). Husserl & CM only have a chapter but (though of course you must judge for yourself) it's fairly clear.

Husserl is not the most lucid of writers, as you will have found, but these two references might help. Good luck !